# Display a part of database data after redirect by clicking specific button - Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, laravel

Hello guys I'm new to Laravel and programming.

This is my controller here I'm trying to get all the Reference ['1','2','3',etc.] from MasterListing table. I also have a reference column in DetailListing table(2nd line).

```
public function show(DetailListing $id)   

{
        $d =  \App\MasterListing::pluck('Reference');
        $data = \App\DetailListing::where('reference',$d)->get();
        return view('detaillisting',['data'=>$data]);
    }
```

master listing page(https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4s5A.jpg), 
**HTML for master listing page**

```
 <tbody>
           @foreach ($data as $row)
            <tr>
            <td> {{ $row->id }} </td>
            <td> {{ $row->Name }} </td>
            <td> {{ $row->Description }} </td>
            <td> {{ $row->Type }} </td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href = 'detaillisting/{{ $row->id }}';">BROWSE</button></td>
            </tr>

            @endforeach
      </tbody>
```

Route

```
Route::get('/detaillisting/{id}','DetailTestController@show');
```

What I expect is when I click on #1 BROWSE, it should redirect me to detail listing page and show DetailListing data with only reference '1', when I click on #2 BROWSE it should only show data with reference '2', etc.

But it resulted showing all data with reference '1' no matter I click on which button.

This has troubled me for a long time, really appreciate your help!

Comment: You are passing `$id` in `show()` But you never used it, Then why are you passing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your route I see you are not passing an object if type DetailListing but an int or a string, I suppose this is the reference value in detailListing table?

```
public function show($id)   
{
    $data = \App\DetailListing::where('reference',$id)->get();
    return view('detaillisting',['data'=>$data]);
}
```